# OpenGL : Texturing inside a cube

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I'm trying to texture the inside of a big cube which has all my drawn objects,so that the cube can act as a skybox. First, I'm just trying out normal cube texturing, and *not* cubemap texturing yet.

I read an answer on SO which said that if I reverse the order of passing my triangle vertices, then the cube will be drawn inside-out. Earlier, for normal external face texturing, I was passing cube vertices in counter-clockwise order. So for internal face texturing I passed my coordinates (via indices) , in the clockwise order.

The image pasted below is what I'm getting. The "robot" is inside the big surrounding cube, on which a night sky image has been applied as texture. It's not working properly. It's a closed cube with internal texturing. But check behind the "robot", there is a black area with no night sky texture applied. Why is this happening? :

[image: Black Area without texture]

Comment: Its one face that went black. Check your texture coordinates. You might as well give each face its own 4 vertices so the texcoords of different faces are independent. But what have you got against cubemaps?

Comment: It may me due to clipping distance, try adjusting near and far clip in your projection matrix.

Comment: or you want to have a skybox, that is done by drawing the cube smaller after clearing the screen and disabling writing to the depth buffer during that pass

Comment: @j-p Thanks, that was the problem!